# why "|" doesn't work for combine serval regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on regular express for JavaScript.
And the regular expression works if I write like this:

```
let print = res.replace("[0;32m"," ").replace("[0m"," ").replace("[0;31m"," ");
```

However, I want to combine these three into one regular expression, and it doesn't work.
Which's wrong about my code?

```
// try this
let print = res.replace("[0;32m"|"[0m"|"[0;31m)", " ");
// and try this,too
let print = res.replace(("[0;32m")|("[0m")|("[0;31m"), " ");
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `.replace("[0;32m"," ")` is not using a regular expression, it's a normal string replacement.

Comment: That's a string, not a regex. (And logical OR operators on strings?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main reasons for this:

- You aren't using regular expressions. You are using plain strings.
- You aren't using `|` *inside* a regular expression, or even inside a string. It's a [Bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) in that context.

If you want a regular expression then you need to write one using regular expression syntax (so you need to mark the groups that you are ORing and escape special characters).

```js
const input = "test[;32mtest";
const result = input.replace(/(?:\[;32m)|(?:\[;0m)|(?:\[;31m)/, " ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @LiLian — Works fine in the live demo in the answer.

Comment: You need to do a global search + it's `[0;32m` not `[;32m`.

Comment: @WaisKamal — Only to replace beyond the first one, which the original code didn't do.

Comment: If the string contains all of the three substrings the OP intends to match, then after the first `replace()` replaces the first string, the next one would replace the second, and the last would replace the third. Hence a global search is required as per the OP's requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Put them in a character group:

```js
let res = "A string that contains [0;32m and [0m and [0;31m";
let print = res.replace(/(\[0;32m)|(\[0m)|(\[0;31m)/g, " ")
console.log(print);
```